# Параллельное выполнение метод(а)ов/функции без использования потоков

Tags: c#, асинхронность, .net

Собственно сабж. Есть ли способы? Есть метод, его надо выполнить много раз, отличие только в том что для каждого метода разные входные данные. Хотелось бы увеличить производительность выполняя эти методы параллельно.

Comment: Без использования потоков это невозможно. Параллельное выполнение в системе (по крайней мере в Win) реализуется через потоки. Однако можно работать с ними неявно - Task и Async в .Net 4.0.

Comment: а почему нельзя использовать потоки? просто интересно. тем более, как было сказано выше, без использования потоков сделать подобное в .Net невозможно - все паттерны асинхронного программирования основаны на потоках!

Comment: ну у меня несколько сотен методов одновременно будут выполняться, будут проблемы с производительностью, вот и думаю как это сделать

Comment: Определить количество процессорных ядер в системе, создать соответственное количество тредов и каждому треду назначить очередь выполняющихся методов, разделив их всех на равные или примерно равные куски.

Comment: а сколько максимально потоков на ядро можно использовать? (работа с сетью)

Comment: >ну у меня несколько сотен методов одновременно будут выполняться, будут проблемы с производительностью, вот и думаю как это сделать
``ThreadPool`` или статический класс ``Parallel`` и ``PLINQ`` как раз и предназначены для подобных ситауций

Comment: А у ThreadPool есть ограничения на количество потоков? И в чем отличие между ThreadPool,Parallel,PLINQ ? код проекта довольно большой

Comment: ``ThreadPool`` автоматически выполняет синхронизацию и переключение между потоками, поэтому вам об этом можно не беспокоится, а их кол-во достаточно велико, чтобы не увеличивать, т.к. можете только ухудшить производительность

``PLINQ`` и ``Parallel`` очень хорошо справляются с незавиисмыми друг от друга данными и хорошо работают, если у вас более одного процессора

более подробно погуглите...

Comment: Объясните, почему у Вас ожидается **несколько сотен** параллельных потоков. Они реально что-то считают все время ? Или большинство ждет ввода/вывода и т.п. ?

Т.е. в чем суть задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, на данный момент придумали только два вида параллелизма : через процессы и через потоки.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Timer.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace Timers
{
   class Program
   {
      int TimesCalled = 0;

      void Display (object state)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", (string)state, ++TimesCalled);
      }

      static void Main( )
      {
         Program p = new Program();

         Timer myTimer = new Timer
            (p.Display, "Обработка", 
               2000,   // Первый раз метод будет вызван через 2 секунды
               1000);  // Повтор каждую секунду
         Console.WriteLine("Таймер запущен.");

         Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Когда истекает время, таймер вызывает метод в определённом потоке, ставя ему в соответствие аргумент state (в нашем случае строка "Обработка").

В данном примере каждую секунду, начиная со второй будут выводится строки:

```
"Обработка" 1
"Обработка" 2
"Обработка" 3
"Обработка" 4
"Обработка" 5
...
```

Чтобы таймер, мог вызвать метод, он (метод) должен соответствовать делегату TimerCallback:

```
void TimerCallback(object state)
```

Comment: это с таймером то увеличивать производительность? нуну

Comment: Думаю, создатели Timer, постарались реализовать его так, что ВЫ ВРЯД ЛИ сумеете реализовать быстрее, тогда: зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Речь о том, что Timer вызывает метод последовательно, а не параллельно, и делает это в одном потоке.

Comment: Речь не об реализации своего таймера. Вопрошающий желает увеличить производительность, реализуя псевдопараллельное выполнение нескольких (сотен) функций. Он не хочет использовать штатный механизм потоков, потому что подозревает, что он слишком затратный. По времени я так думаю. А у Вас функции вызываются по таймеру раз в секунду. И всю эту секунду компьютер пинает ваньку